# How to get and set lightuserdata

Tags: lua

I want to store a pointer into the lua_State object, and retrieve that pointer in callbacks.
It's just the same, single pointer, in all callbacks. I think what I need is `lightuserdata`, but I can't find complete examples on how to set and fetch the pointer.

I just need something this simple:

```
void SetPointer(lua_State* L, void* p) {
    lua_pushlightuserdata (l, p);
    // What else to do?
}

void GetPointer(lua_State* L) {
    // How to get the lightuserdata?
}
```

I can do it either using the raw Lua API or using the Sol wrapper library [1]

[1] https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2

Comment: Why not store it in a C variable?  Do you have multiple Lua states?  Lightuserdata may be passed to Lua (as a value) and Lua will later pass it to your C function, which will be able to extract the pointer from this Lua value (of type lightuserdata)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you really don't want to use full userdata (in most cases you want). Read e.g., [PIL 28.5 - Light Userdata](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.5.html) to get a better idea.

To use light userdata you need to manage its lifetime in C side and availability in Lua all on your own. To set and get light userdata on/from Lua stack use respectively: [`lua_pushlightuserdata`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_pushlightuserdata) and [`lua_touserdata`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_touserdata) (this function is shared with full userdata). You can also use [`lua_topointer`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_topointer) to read the pointer value; note that it has wider and slightly different use.

To allocate and make it available:

```c
char* obj = malloc(2);  // lifetime managed by C
obj[0] = 'U';
obj[1] = 0;
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, obj);
lua_setglobal(L, "ptr");  // make it available to Lua via global variable
```

Afterwards, you can use it in Lua:

```lua
print(ptr)  --> userdata: 0x556be32ba2e0
another = ptr
```

And in C:

```c
lua_getglobal(L, "another");  // another global from the previous sample
void* ref1 = lua_touserdata(L, -1);
printf("%p\n", ref1);  //: 0x556be32ba2e0
const void* ref2 = lua_topointer(L, -1);
printf("%p\n", ref2);  //: 0x556be32ba2e0
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Finally, you will need to free the allocated object at the correct spot:

```c
free(obj);  // again, lifetime managed by C
```

Now, where is "the correct spot"? Well... It's where you would usually put it when writing in pure C: when you (or your user) no longer need it or never (e.g., if you like memory leaks, your program is short-lived or object lifetime is same as program lifetime).

As an alternative to global variable, you may put the pointer into the [Registry](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.3). This will make it accessible to you via the Lua state in C but not from the Lua side:

```c
char* obj;  // initialize it as before
lua_pushstring(L, "myprogram_that_one_object");  // prefix your key, registry is shared with all libraries
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, obj);
lua_settable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

Then, in possibly another scope, when you want to use or free it:

```c
lua_pushstring(L, "myprogram_that_one_object");
lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
char* obj = lua_touserdata(L, -1);
free(obj);  // or use it
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

If you use full userdata, Lua will manage the lifetime of the object for you (it will be garbage collected just like normal Lua values).

Comment: I only want this to be available on the C size, not to Lua scripts. Is it necessary to use `lua_setglobal(L, "ptr")` ?

Comment: If you want it only on the C side, then you don't need userdata at all, light or full. If you want to bind it to Lua state nonetheless without making it visible to Lua, use [Registry](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.3).

Comment: @Dess see updated answer that uses registry, maybe this will be of help, but then again - if you don't plan to make it available in Lua, then why put it into Lua in the first place. The only reason I see at quick review is consistent global state management.